# mysql stored procedure construct with GROUP_CONCAT and IN clause

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

For some reason i need to explode a query in multisteps (very large rows and many join) , **I know its possible to perform the query like SELECT IN (subquery) but its not what i need to achieve.**

How to construct my query into step where query 2 can use the result of query 1 (without using temporary table) with an IN clause ; expected query 2 should look like this : select otherstuff where foo IN(id,id,id,id,longlistid,)

query 1 => select stuf as result1 
query 2 => select otherstuf where foo IN (result1)

**I thought to use shortcut @ don't know if its appropriate , here is my try :**

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE `exemple`()
    BEGIN

     SELECT @query1 := 
    `id`  FROM `table`
    WHERE `stuf`= 'cat'
    UNION ALL SELECT `id`
    FROM `table`
    WHERE `dog`= 'hard' ;

    SELECT please FROM help WHERE me IN(@query1) ;

    END
```

The IN clause seems not correct like this..

**Another try , store result in a declared locale variable :**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `exemple`()
    BEGIN

     DECLARE resultquery1 VARCHAR(5000);

    SELECT 
    `id`  FROM `table`
    WHERE `stuf`= 'cat'
    UNION ALL SELECT `id`
    FROM `table`
    WHERE `dog`= 'hard' 
    INTO resultquery1 ;

    SELECT please FROM help WHERE me IN(resultquery1) ;

    END
```

Not enought , i got this logical error :
Error Code: 1172. Result consisted of more than one row

regards,
Jess

Comment: thx to try help me, i'm very new with store..and don't know what is Table type variable, a concret example could seriously help me

Comment: Sorry that's a mistake. There is no Table type variable in `MySQL`. rather use a `temporary` table.

Comment: Just curious .. the way you are trying (per post) in variable ... are you sure that will be efficient? did you bench-marked that as well? If yes, then the syntax issue can be taken care off.

Comment: we are tlking about millions rows..so yes benchmark was serious.

Comment: the ideal solution should be to store result of query1 in an declare array variable (inside the SP) and reuse it to perform the second query within IN clause.  something like declare temp varchar(1000) ; select what i need INTO temp ; select with second query2 IN (temp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `Temporary Table` instead and have the query1 value inserted in that table. then in your query2 you can directly fetch the data from temporary table; like below (A code sample)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `exemple`()
BEGIN

create temporary table temptest(col varchar(20));
insert into temptest
 SELECT `foo`  FROM `table`
WHERE `stuf`= 'cat'
UNION ALL SELECT `bar`
FROM `table`
WHERE `dog`= 'hard' ;

SELECT please FROM help WHERE me IN (select distinct col from temptest) ;

DROP TABLE temptest;
END
```

**EDIT:**

You may not need the temporary table at all. Per your post explanation, you can  include the query directly in `IN` clause like below. Hope this helps.

```
 SELECT please FROM help 
 WHERE me IN (
     SELECT `foo`  FROM `table`
    WHERE `stuf`= 'cat'
    UNION ALL SELECT `bar`
    FROM `table`
    WHERE `dog`= 'hard'
    ) ;
```

**FINAL EDIT:**

A inlist is a comma separated value, you can't simply store like the way you are trying cause it's a scalar variable where you are trying to store and it's incorrect;

You may do little trick like below and store it but that's not guaranteed to work.

```
set @inlist := (
select group_concat(unitid)
from (
SELECT unitid, 1 as 'ID'  FROM teachers
    WHERE username= 'abcdced'
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT unitid, 1 as 'ID'  FROM teachers
    WHERE username= 'harikas'
) x
group by ID);
```

Moreover, I am not sure who told you that going through variable will be efficient.

I may agree that `TEMPORARY` table may pose some issue based on your situation but
the subquery option I given (Or the suggestion provided by Gordon in below answer) will be much efficient than the way you are trying to do. At least it will not incurr the cost of fetching and storing into variables (If at all it works).

Comment: wow temporary table let me bad memorys..If its the only way to do that , perhaps i should thinking to keep my actual patern who is : 9 basic query from php ..?

Comment: @albator, no it's not always bad. if you need then use them ... just make sure to drop/free them once done. see edited answer.

Comment: actually i have 9 claasical querys to construct this query , do you think i shloud go for a store procedure with a temporary table or keep my actual patern from php who is : mysql_query(query1),mysql_query(query2), etc..

Comment: @albator, always go for stored procedure and not 9 different queries. that way you are unnecessarily making 9 different request/call. Read about advantages of SP over normal query.

Comment: @albator, Missed that! see edited answer. You may not need the temp table at all.

Comment: thx but i can't , the final query is very huge  and can perform good only with a list of IN . It was benchmarked from long time..

Comment: i made some test and the temporary table is pretty horible as usual :) i'm pretty sure there are better solution , i continu to investigate

Comment: is it possible you edit ur answer and delete the subquery proposition please, because i edited my post and now it makes no more sens, sorry for that

Comment: @albator, for you it may not make sense (though I am not sure why) but for future readers it may and so it's not possible for me to delete that part of answer and for the same reason I believe your edit request got rejected too.

Comment: @albator, see edited answer (`Final Edit` part) if it makes sense to you. Finally it's your choice how you want to go.

Comment: thx,ur final edit help me to achieve with the (magic) group_concat !

Comment: Concerning the subquery..There are some case who its better to cutt the query , in my case the query is a massive query with many join with a geoloc in it , after all benchs , the faster way was appear to use an IN clause with many postal code ids.. Just in case ur curious about it , there are some cases where subquery isnot the good choice..

Answer (score 1):

I add an answer here To follow the @Rahul correct answer in final edit , for thoses who need to achieve this particular case  (when subquery cannot perform as well you'd like) ,
here is the final form of the procedure using the mysql GROUP_CONCAT and CONCAT function : 
**temp is the declared local variable for storing first result 

SET SESSION group concat to avoid the group_concat limitation length**

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE `exemple`()
    BEGIN

    DECLARE temp VARCHAR(10000); 
    SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 100000; 

    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(foo) FROM bar
    WHERE cible = x GROUP BY cible INTO temp; 

    SET @S = CONCAT
   (
    "SELECT * FROM anothertable WHERE whatyouwant IN(", temp," ) "
   );

    PREPARE STMT FROM @S;
    EXECUTE STMT;   

    END
```

Answer (score 0):

Often the most efficient way to approach this is with two conditions in the `where` clause:

```
select please
from help h
where exists (select 1
              from table t1
              where stuf = 'cat' and h.me = t1.foo
             ) or
      exists (select 1
              from table t1
              where dog = 'hard' and h.me = t1.bar
             );
```

These queries can take advantage of indexes on the table used in the subquery:  `table(foo, cat)` and `table(bar, hard)`.

Comment: on huge tables and big results the time uses to explode query then use IN(id,id,id) is preferable in my case;